# Hibernate Collection Initailization issue

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am new to Hibernate and I am facing a issue. There is a existing Class which is getting loaded using Hibernate.  I want to add a Set to that class. And added this block in the Existing parent hbm.xml.

```
<set name="assocication" table="AssociationLinks"  lazy="false" access="field" cascade="lock">
      <cache usage="read-only" region="UpstreamLink.AssociationLinks"/>
        <key column="COUNTRY_TKEY" foreign-key="COUNTRY_ID" property-ref="countryID"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.AssociationLinks" />
    </set>
```

Child Hbm.xml

```
<class name="AssociationLinks" table="AssociationLinks">
    <cache usage="read-only" region="UpstreamLink.AssociationLinks" />
    <id name="countryID" type="string" column="COUNTRY_ID" access="field" />

    <property name="entityName" column="ENTITY_NAME" type="java.lang.String" access="field" />


</class>
```

When i add Lazy= true in parent I get the Exception:

```
  016-07-05 03:49:43,680 ERROR  org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.MainData.association, no session or session was closed
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.MainData.association, no session or session was closed
            at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
            at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
            at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
            at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
```

But when i make lazy = false, i am seeing that value in getting in one place, but the place where my Parent class's Parent is accessed, i get the below error.

```
2016-07-05 07:49:00,005 INFO   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - Error performing load command
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:794)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:241)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)
```